# ffmpeg v4l2 driver changes framerate of Logitech c920 camera

Tags: video, ffmpeg, v4l, v4l2loopback

I own a Logitech c920 camera which seems to be able to do at least 24fps for 1080p (although the specs say it should go up to 60), according to `vlc -vvv --color v4l2:///dev/video0 --run-time 1 vlc://quit -I dummy -V dummy -A dummy` for which I get the lines:

```
[00007f64f4001120] v4l2 demux debug:  frame size 1920x1080
[00007f64f4001120] v4l2 demux debug:   discrete frame interval: 1/24
```

However, when I attempt to use ffmpeg to copy `video0` to a v4l2 loopback device using:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -r 24 -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video4
```

I get only 10fps and the message:

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x55a30e698c00] The driver changed the time per frame from 1/24 to 1/10
```

Why is this happening and how can I get a higher framerate?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47293391/659002

Answer (score 3):

You are using RAW format of the camera.
Try using a compressed codec:

```
ffmpeg -vcodec mjpeg -r 30 -s 1920x1080 -f v4l2 ...
```